# How to delete a row from a relationship table using two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete a relationship between table T2 and T3 that is on table T1.
I've searched but I could only find examples of a DELETE with only one INNER JOIN.

I'm trying something like this, but I get a error:

> SQL error: ORA-00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

```
DELETE t1
FROM T1 t1
INNER JOIN T2 t2
  ON t2.ID = t1.ID_t2
INNER JOIN T3 t3  
  ON t3.ID = t1.ID_t3
  WHERE (t3.property1 IN 'XXX' AND 
        t3.property2 = 1 AND 
        t2.property = 'YYY');
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using MySql syntax to delete from an Oracle database.
You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
DELETE FROM T1 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T2 WHERE T2.property = 'YYY' AND T2.ID = T1.ID_t2)
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T3 WHERE T3.property1 = 'XXX' AND T3.property2 = 1 AND T3.ID = T1.ID_t3)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a valid Oracle syntax. Try with `exists`:

```
    DELETE FROM T1 
    where exists 
               (select * from T2 where T2.ID = T1.ID_t2 and T2.property = 'YYY')
    and exists (select * from T3 where T3.ID = T1.ID_t3 and T3.property1 IN ('XXX') AND T3.property2 = 1  ) ;
```

For single value you can use `T3.property1 ='XXX'` instead of `T3.property1 IN ('XXX')`